# Woocommerce disable automatic order status change pending->processing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I want to dissable this option: 
Whenever someone makes and order on my site and the payment is successfull the order status automaticaly changes from **pending to processing**.

However I **don`t want** this feature **to have enabled**. Rather I want to do it manually when i proces the orders.

I found this function in the woocommerce which is making this feature possible. I don`t want to directly change it there but rather with some kind of php snippet which overrides this function.

Here is the function which i need to change : http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_orderpayment_complete/

PS: I just having a hard time to do it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

May be this `payment_complete()` is not involved in the process you are looking for. Alternatively, what you could try is the `woocommerce_thankyou` action hook instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'thankyou_order_status', 10, 1 );
function thankyou_order_status( $order_id ){
    if( ! $order_id ) return;

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); // Get an instance of the WC_Order object

    if ( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) )
            $order-> update_status( 'pending' )
}
```

You can use the same alternative hook: `woocommerce_thankyou_{$order->get_payment_method()}` (replacing `$order->get_payment_method()` by the payment method ID slug)

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

---

Using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment_complete`** filter hook, where you will return the desired orders statuses that can be taken by the related function `payment_complete()` which is responsible of auto change the order status.

By default the array of order statuses in the filter is:

```
array( 'on-hold', 'pending', 'failed', 'cancelled' ).
```

And we can remove 'on-hold' order status this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'disable_auto_order_status', 10, 2 );
function disable_auto_order_status( $order_statuses, $order ) {
    $return array( 'pending', 'failed', 'cancelled' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

Comment: @LaciFeldsam Updated my answer…

Comment: this made the trick. kind off....
working but it sends to custommer that it is in processing because it works like this:
pending->processing->pending

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your `functions.php` file.function

```
ja_order_status( $order_status, $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if ( 'processing' == $order_status ) {
        return 'pending';
    }

    return $order_status;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'ja_order_status', 10, 2 );
```

Tested on **WooCommerce** with **Storefront** paid via **Stripe** *test mode*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is not working for me still the status is changing to processing even on the order page where the notes are I have message that it changed.

Comment: Okay so i commented out the line where it shoud change in that function which a sent the link.
And the status is still changing

Comment: Didn't really get what you're saying in your comment but as stated in my answer, it is working as expected give the above specs.