# Woocommerce disable automatic order status change on-hold->processing，Help~~Why can't work

Tags: woocommerce

add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'disable_auto_order_status', 10, 3 );

function disable_auto_order_status( $order_statuses, $order ) {
         return 'on-hold';

}

Comment: My answer was wrong. The exact answer to your question lies here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46281679/8913606

Comment: I just referenced it but it still doesn't work

Comment: Finally, it works

Comment: Glad you have solved the issue. Post your answer if it has changes from the answer in the link

Comment: Is the link above, I have modified

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Woocommerce disable automatic order status change pending->processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279951/woocommerce-disable-automatic-order-status-change-pending-processing)